# Update Excel formula on another person's workbook

Tags: vba, excel-formula

Does anyone know how to update an excel formula on someone's excel workbook? The problem here is that there 100s of the same kind of workbook in use, and the same formula is incorrect on all the versions, and each workbook has a unique name. Many of these users are not excel savvy. I'm looking to see if I can write something that they can launch on their computer after they open the spreadsheet to update the formula. Thank you.

From this AN9
=SUM(Y23:Y24,X79,Y84:**Y85**/
 SUM(X23:X24,Y79,X84:**X85**)

to this AN9
=SUM(Y23:Y24,X79,Y84:**Y105**/
 SUM(X23:X24,Y79,X84:**X105**)

Comment: Is the formula always on the same sheet in the workbook ? Do the users have admin credentials on their machine ? A powershell script could do the trick (shipped with Windows 7 and above).

Comment: @E.Wiest Yes, it's always the same. Unfortunately, users do not have admin rights.

Comment: OK. I've posted something. Can you read it and tell me : if the replacement has to be cell specific, if the formula I've fixed is OK (missing ")"), and if the script works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

I can propose this powershell script :

```
$EXECUTIONPOLICY = Get-ExecutionPolicy
Set-Executionpolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
$old='SUM(Y23:Y24,X79,Y84:Y85)/ SUM(X23:X24,Y79,X84:X85)'
$new='SUM(Y23:Y24,X79,Y84:Y85)/ SUM(X23:X24,Y79,X84:X105)'
Get-ChildItem ".\*.xlsx" | Copy-Item -Destination "excel.zip"
Expand-Archive excel.zip -DestinationPath excel
Get-Item ".\excel\xl\worksheets\*.xml"| ForEach {(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Replace($old,$new) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName}
Compress-Archive -Path ".\excel\*" -DestinationPath excel -Force
Rename-Item "excel.zip" -NewName "new.xlsx"
Remove-Item excel -Recurse
Set-ExecutionPolicy $EXECUTIONPOLICY
```

[Script PS1](https://covid19.framadrop.org/lufi/r/2FnX3tJmtN#CxDIEwV7reBRML796giMDC9mujcmM4I4ySNsMR6q2lM=)

What the script does :

It replaces a specific formula. Please note the replacement is not cell-specific (cell AN9). I've assumed the formula appears only 1 time per sheet.

If the replacement needs absolutely to be cell-specific (in case of the "wrong formula" still has to exist elsewehere on the same sheet), we can fix the code later.

The script support any workbook regardless its name. It also support multiple sheets. So anywhere the formula is found, it will be replaced  (sheet 1, sheet 2, sheet 3, sheet 4, mysheet, sales, ...)

How to use it :

1.Put the .xlsx file in a folder of your choice. There must be ONLY one .xlsx file in the folder, the one you want to fix.
2.Put the .ps1 script in the same folder.
3.Right-click on the .ps1 script, then "Run with Powershell".

A new file is created : "new.xlsx"

Other:

I have to fix your Excel formula (missing ")"). I hope that's correct.
I'm not 100% sure the script will be executed without admin rights. Even with this excution policy bypass.